# How to display auth errors with p tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

how to display to user an auth error differently than with alert?
For example: User will type a bad password, and a p tag will tell him, that he typed uncorrect password.
Using Firebase v9 and React.

Some code:

```
    import React from 'react'
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { UserAuth } from '../context/AuthContext';
import { useState } from 'react';



const Signin = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const { signIn } = UserAuth();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setError('')
    try{
        await signIn(email, password)
        navigate("/");
    } catch (e) {
      setError(e.message)
      alert(e.message)
      
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className='Signin'>Signin
    
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
         
            <label>Email</label>
            <input onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} type="email"/>
            <label>password</label>
            <input onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} type="password"/>
            <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
            <p className='errorp'></p>
            
        </form>
    
    </div>
  )
}
```

export default Signin

Thank you!

Comment: What is not working as intended in this code? Can you share complete code that shows where `setError` is declared and the `<p>` tag that you are referring to ?

Comment: I do not have a p tag, but i want to display the error as a p tag. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `{error && <p className='errorp'>{error}</p>}`

Comment: Thank you so much! But do you know, how to edit these errors? Example-- Firebase: Error (auth/wrong-password). But if I just simply want: Uncorrect pass or email, how do I can do it?

Comment: You can check for the error type when you catch it, and then set your custom error when you call `setError`  in the `catch` block.  So if your caught error type is for ex `auth/wrong-password`, you can then do `setError('Incorrect Password')`

Comment: Again, thank you. But when error is incorrect password, and i have in setError("too many requests"), how can I display the actual error?

Comment: @Simon, I believe you need to look more into the docs of Firebase Auth, so you know the type of errors the library returns. Also,  search on how to do proper error handling in react , lots of videos and documentation out there. For you current case it seems that Firebase is limiting your network calls as you must be spamming them with requests.